# Lyx cannot discover enumitem.sty

Tags: pdftex, lyx, enumerate, itemize, enumitem

I tried putting enumitem.sty in the same folder as the lyx file.

I tried putting enumitem.sty into C:\texlive\2019\texmf-dist\tex\latex\enumitem

I tried just Tools->Reconfigure after that.

But still, if I open a lyx document, it says

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: you shouldn't need to install it manually. But if you do a better location is probably `C:\texlive\texmflocal\tex\latex\enumitem`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  Following your advice, I just put enumitem to that folder, and then did Tools->Reconfigure again. But the same error remains.

Comment: sorry I have no idea where lyx looks (and depending on your installation it could even use miktex or something else). Try to find a log-file which tells you something about the search pathes.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer How can I find out which directory lyx is using for style files?